# UI for controlling a robotic arm

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey , i recently started working on robotic manipulators .

I have in my possession a 6DOF , servo based robotic arm , run using PCA9685 and Arduino(ros_serial is used ).
I can control the arm vai RQT or "rostopic pub **** ".

Before moving onto move_it module , i want to manually control the robotic arm using a UI .

**I was thinking something like a web based UI with sliders for controlling the individual servos ,** *how may i proceed ?*

How do people generally control robotic arms vai manual method?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287096/ui-for-controlling-a-robotic-arm/) by [chrissunny94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33207/chrissunny94/) on ROS Answers with karma: 142 on 2018-03-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If your robot has a `ros_control` compatible `hardware_interface` configured with an instance of the `joint_trajectory_controller`, you could use [rqt_joint_trajectory_controller](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_joint_trajectory_controller) (from [here](http://rtmros-nextage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual_ja_tutorial_3d-perception.html)):

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chrissunny94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33207/chrissunny94/) on 2018-03-30**:
Can i get a web-based UI , using a simple slider such as available on RQT

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-31**:
Probably. I do not know of one though.

**Comment by [chrissunny94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33207/chrissunny94/) on 2018-03-31**:
Thanks anyways